# How To Find Nearest Point From User Location using geodjango?

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am trying to find the nearest point to a location using geodjango.

I tried using the following code:

```
LocationInfo.objects.filter(coordinates__distance_lte=(user_location, D(km=2)))
```

But It only works if the location is within the specified distance (`D(km=2)` in this case).

I need to find the point nearest to the user without using any limit during query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's assume that your `LocationInfo` has it's geometry field named `position`:

**For Django version >= 1.9:**

You can use the [`Distance()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance) function:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

LocationInfo.objects.annotate(
    distance=Distance('position', user_location)
).order_by('distance').first()
```

Which will return the nearest object to the `user_location`

**For Django  1.6 <= version < 1.9:**

You can use the [`.distance()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance) method:

```
LocationInfo.objects.distance(user_location).order_by('distance').first()
```

**For Django version < 1.6:**

The `.first()` method does not exist so you have to get the first of the ordered queryset as follows:

```
 LocationInfo.objects.distance(user_location).order_by('distance')[:1].get()
```

Comment: I am facing the following error: TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) on trying out the above code

Comment: I am using django 1.11 in the project.

Comment: Did you imported `Distance` like so: `from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance`?

Comment: No. I was using the one from from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance. It works after importing from the db source. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know mate, I will edit my answer to include this :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the nearest location info:

```
LocationInfo.geo_objects.distance(user_location).order_by('distance')[0]
```

where geo_objects is Model manager for LocationInfo

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class LocationInfo(models.Model):

    geo_objects = gis_models.GeoManager()
```